# What is an adjective that means 'inciting violence?'

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, american-english

I'm looking for a word that could be used to describe a street preacher who is intentionally riling up a crowd to get people to attack a specific individual, based on a mix of xenophobia and religious fervor. I've found words like 'odious' and of course 'xenophobic' to indicate hatred, but I'm looking for something that is specific to inciting violence.

Sample sentence: The _____ preacher held Cade's gaze only for a moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Inflammatory](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inflammatory)

> tending to excite anger, disorder, or tumult

Synonyms: [incendiary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incendiary) (roughly the same definition), and [seditious](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sedition) (appealing to unlawful insurrection against authority)

Of the three, seditious might be the best choice to use if you want to say that the preacher wants a full on riot, but inflammatory is my personal pick.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe simply:

inciteful

> adjective
>  (of words, actions, etc.) offering incitement.
>   [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/inciteful)
>
> incite
>  Encourage or stir up (violent or unlawful behaviour) ‘they
>   conspired to incite riots’
>   1.1 Urge or persuade (someone) to act in a violent or unlawful way. ‘he incited loyal subjects to rebellion’
>  [Oxford Living
>   Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/incite)